# Change ACO and ARO model in cakephp 2.3.6

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to change ACO and ARO model in cakephp for using in ACL,
In fact I want to just add a behavior to them.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own Aco and Aro models and add the behaviour as any other behaviour to them. You can copy the models from the CakePHP core to your app. They're included there to make the ACL work out of the box with these default models